# A script that only deletes fields within an attribute table specified by the user

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I would like a script that will be executed in ArcGIS that only deletes fields within an attribute table that are specified by the user. As I understand it, this can be done in Modelbuilder but was curious if I script would do the same.

When I say specified by the user, I wish the script tool to give the user all the fields within the attribute table and allow them to select which ones they wish to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the [Delete Field tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004n000000) within the Fields toolbox?

```
ArcToolbox --> Data Management Tools --> Fields --> Delete Field
```

Choose your input table/feature class, and select the fields you want to remove.

If you want to script it out to delete certain fields every time, it'd be pretty easy.

```
arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_table, drop_field)
```

Example from the documentation:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.DeleteField_management("C:/output/roads.shp", ["STREET_NAM", "LABEL", "CLASS"])
```

Comment: The only part of the question this doesn't address is giving the user all the fields within the attribute table (though I wonder why this is a requirement).

Comment: It does if you use the actual ESRI tool. When you select the input table/feature class, it lists all the fields. However, you're correct on the scripting part, but I also don't see why that'd be necessary. They might as well just use the built-in tool.

Comment: Listing all the fields in attribute (and not using the built in feature) is something that is required (ie: I would like to do it). If it's not possible, I can keep it as a Modelbuilder.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do? Do you want this as like a command line tool that lists all the fields, and the user chooses which ones to remove?

Comment: Precisely. I would like it to be like a command tool, list all the fields and have the user select which one they want to drop.

Comment: Well, it's definitely possible. You'd just have to get user input for the feature class, use arcpy.Describe() to list the fields, and then use arcpy.DeleteField_management to remove the ones you want.

Comment: arcpy.ListFields is the way to go to get a list of fields.